# OS portable C/C++ XML parser

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing

What is the fastest C/C++ open source, OS portable XML parser that has both Unicode support and XML Schema support?

Comment: I've found out that PugiXML http://pugixml.org/benchmark/ is the fastest OS Portable one, AsmXML is faster but only works for x86 processors. PugiXML does not support XML Schemas though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as "the best ...", but [Xerces-C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) is a powerful one, which has XML Schema support, and [pugixml](http://pugixml.org/documentation/) is a very neat one, however, which doesn't validate

Answer (score 1):

A commonly used xml library is libxml2 available [here](http://www.xmlsoft.org/).

Comment: Could not find 64 bit binaries, only 32-bit?

Comment: http://www.xmlsoft.org/downloads.html Under "Binary ports:". Of course, most distributions will have their own binary compiled from source.

Comment: http://xmlsoft.org/sources/win32/64bit/readme.txt Can't link statically. Very portable isn't it?